# Silverlight Cross-domain issue with WCF self-hosted in windows service

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, cross-domain, self-hosting

I have a Silverlight application that is running perfectly in my local machine, consuming WCF services form a development server (self-hosted in windows services).

I have to debug one of the WCF services, in order to find the root cause of a bug. I added my debug/tracing info in the service, and installed in a virtual machine (and even locally), but since then, I get the well-known cross-domain error:

> "An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI
>   'http://MyVMMachine:4096/MyService'. This could be due to attempting
>   to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper
>   cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP
>   services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish
>   a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP
>   headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal
>   types in the web service proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception
>   for more details."

That's strange, because if consuming from a dev server, it works fine, but if installing the service in a dev machine, or even locally (self-hosted in windows service as well), it doesn't work.

Here is the service original code:

```
public partial class WindowsService : ServiceBase
{
    ServiceHost _Host;

    public WindowsService()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Server.One.Log("Windows service initialization failed: " + exc.Message);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Server.One.Start();
            _Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
            _Host.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Server.One.Log("Windows service start failed: " + exc.Message);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_Host != null)
                _Host.Close();
            Server.One.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Server.One.Log("Windows service stop failed: " + exc.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

After reading [Carlos Figueira's article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Accessing-self-hosted-WCF-7872c931) on this subject, I changed the service applying his approach, but still not working.

Any ideas???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with fiddler to see where is your application really asking for your service.

This has happened to me a couple of times and it usually was because of server port changes 8-)

Just change your ServiceReferences.ClientConfig to the server port.

Take a look at your Service project configuration (web tab) and set the specific port as 4096 if you want to call it there:

[image]

Comment: Hey. I already did (I should have posted that). The app is requesting both files. Result 400 for clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml files. I have both there, but because this is a self-hosted, I don't think it is able to get it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did already change the clientconfig to the right server/port. About the web tab, since this is a windows service, I don't think that I would have one in the service side.

Comment: Ouch, I didn't realize it wasn't a web project xD

Comment: If you already did it you should post an answer for next visitors ;-)